# How to remove / disable console.log() from a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, console.log

I am pushing code to production that uses a package that calls console.log() every time I call a specific one of its functions.

This function gets called thousands of times simultaneously in my code and I do not want the logging to slow down the execution time or clutter the logs.

On local I have gone into the node module and commented the log out, but production is auto deployed and just runs npm install before running.

Is there a way for me to either comment out the line in production in a way that it will not come back every time it auto deploys or a way for me to ban console logs from the module?

Comment: Depending on your bundler, you may be able to configure your bundler to remove any console interaction. Many bundlers do this with the right config. Otherwise, include one in your build process that would scour and remove the console interaction at build time.

Comment: Webpack plug-in example of my above comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#terseroptions

Comment: The problem is that console.log is global and will affect thirdparty libs that may provide useful output. Use a package like 'debug' that allows to configure the amount of output and also the scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` itself can be overwritten with an empty function.

```
// backup just in case you need it later somewhere
var oldConsoleLog = window.console.log;
window.console.log = () => {};
```

However, it's recommended to do some investigation on the troublesome package, most packages log only in their development build, maybe there is a production version of the package you should use.

Also, there is some babel/webpack plugin that can remove the console statements for you. For example babel-plugin-transform-remove-console

Comment: The default `console.log` doesn't return anything, so if you log **its** return then sure you'll get `undefined`. @lastr2d2's suggestion will behave the same in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can try redefining the console.log function by writing `console.log = function() {}` at the beginning.